# getting output from command in a vim buffer

Tags: vim

what i want to do

1. editing one file
2. run '!svn diff %' (or any other command that takes the **current file name**)
3. put the output on a new buffer (or tab)

bonus: not using a script, as i work often on hosts i do not manage to my liking.

My first try was: `:tabnew | r !svn diff %` which obvious does not work because % will be empty as it is parsed after the tabnew command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
:tabnew | r !svn diff #
```

`#` references the previous buffer, i.e. the buffer you had open before the `:tabnew` was executed.

Even better is

```
:tabnew | set buftype=nowrite | r !svn diff #
```

because then vim won't complain when you close the tab, but this is already too much to type everytime.

Comment: This is a really powerful pattern!  I wish I knew about that pipe command before.